# How can I determine who is using a given public IP address without DPI?

Tags: network-discovery

Perhaps this sounds like a dumb question but hear me out: I'd like to determine who the service provider is for a given public IP address. I'm not talking about who owns it–that information is readily available–but instead who is actually using it.

Let's take Netflix for example: if I see a stream of packets to a Netflix server and look up the owner of that destination IP I will invariably get Amazon because Netflix (like many service providers) run on Amazon.

How could I identify that it is Netflix who is providing the service without doing DPI on the TLS handshake? (you can guess the service provider pretty well from the raw data stream as the server's hostname will be there in plain text)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is you can't do this reliably without DPI and often not then. You might be able to watch DNS queries to get at some info, but I would consider that DPI. And, you maybe able to get some identifying information from some IP assignments through watching Radius. Again, that's DPI.

The reason I say maybe not even with DPI is because so much stuff is encrypted now.

Note that people who lease or assign IPs are required to retain identifying information for law enforcement purposes. But, that is done using back office systems, nothing in band. That's why Tor networking and other anonymity techniques have developed.